# Getting Started demo for ag-grid - not showing grid as expected

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to get a handle on the "ag-grid" Typescript grid component for my Angular 6 apps.

The website looks very promising, and I've been trying to get their "Getting Started" demo to work on my machine - without any luck so far.

I've gone through the setup steps - with one exception: I tried to use "straight" CSS (instead of going with SCSS) - and thus I have this in my `app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css',
              '../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css',
              '../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css',
             ]
})
```

instead of their approach of importing the CSS in the `styles.scss` file:

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

Not sure, if that's the root cause of the problem - but my data appears on screen very garbled and not in a grid at all .... (tried in both Chrome and Edge - same result):

[image]

Comment: try adding the css import in .angular-cli.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the styles to your `angular.json` file:

`"styles": [
    "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
    "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"
]`

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vaf8la) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've forgotten to replace `ag-theme-alpine` to `ag-theme-balham` in parent `div`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30142616)